# Как правильно разместить разметку?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. На основном экране разметки `LinearLayout` находятся два `layout`'а — `RelativeLayout` с меню и `LinearLayout` с фрагментами. `RelativeLayout` занимает 50dp. LinearLayout занимает всю остальную часть экрана.

Пока меню было вверху, всё было ок. Но как только я поменял их местами, `LinearLayout` занял весь экран (`match_parent`) и `RelativeLayout` скрылся внизу.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_linear_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timer_main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_below_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/clock_rewersed">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fill_day_rate"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fill_day_rate"
            android:onClick="onClickMenu"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/timer" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы `LinearLayout` занимал всю оставшуюся после `RelativeLayout` область, поэтому я не могу задать ему ограничение по высоте. Многочисленные опыты с разметкой и весом ни к чему не привели.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `LinearLayout`, который с id `timer_main_frame`, поставьте высоту `0dp` и свойство `android:layout_weight="1"`. Должно сработать.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!